# How can I translate my JSON structure for jQuery DataTables?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I would like to build a generic CSV viewer with DataTables.

*"generic" means that it should be capable to read any CSV acquired externally and represent into a Jquery DataTables*

I'm starting from a JSON structure (obtained after CSV parsing) and defining this table:

| Name | Surname | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stefano | Rxxxx | 45 |
| Test | Dummy | 50 |

I would then like to show as Jquery DataTables (https://datatables.net/) but it's not clear why I cannot reach my goal:

```js
$(function() {
      data = [
          {"Name":"Stefano","Surname":"Rxxxx","Age":"45"}, 
          {"Name":"Test","Surname":"Dummy","Age":"50"}
      ]
      columns = [];
      $.each(data[0], function(k, v) {
          $('#example > thead > tr').append("<td>" + k + "</td>");
          columns.push(k);
      });
      console.log(columns);
      $('#example').DataTable({
          data: data,
          columns: columns
      });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id='example' class='display'>
<thead><tr></tr></thead>
</table>
```

On consolle I have:

1. a WARNING

> jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Name TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Name

2. an ERROR

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Name

...but it's not clear to me what's wrong or missing in my code to translate a JSON table into a JQUERY DataTables.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your snippet (here in SO) fails with `jquery.dataTables.min.js:126 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'asSorting')` - this is because your `thead` needs a `tr` - add that (and change the corresponding .append and your table loads at least (though has no rows/data): https://jsfiddle.net/45f9ob37/

Comment: This doesn't match the error you've reported, so the snippet doesn't match your code, so we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm a neubie! I've updated the latest library version on my code snippet but I'm still not able to view data in the table :(

Answer (score 1):

Your columns structure is not a valid DataTables structure for columns. It needs (in your case) to define the [`title`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) and the [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) options each column needs to use.

If you change your JavaScript to build that structure, you can use columns: columns successfully (no other changes needed).

You can re-arrange your logic which builds `columns` as follows:

```
$.each(data[0], function(k, v) {
  columns.push({ title: k, data: k });
});
```

This builds the following output:

```js
[ { title: 'Name', data: 'Name' }, { title: 'Surname', data: 'Surname' }, { title: 'Age', data: 'Age' } ]
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  data = [{
      "Name": "Stefano",
      "Surname": "Rxxxx",
      "Age": "45"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Surname": "Dummy",
      "Age": "50"
    }
  ]
  columns = [];
  $.each(data[0], function(k, v) {
    columns.push({
      title: k,
      data: k
    });
  });
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: columns
    //columns: [ { title: 'Name', data: 'Name' }, { title: 'Surname', data: 'Surname' }, { title: 'Age', data: 'Age' } ]

  });
});
```

```css
.display {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id='example' class='display'></table>
</body>
```

Comment: Pardon the edit. I cleaned up the markup and used the Tidy button.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the first object's keys to get your columns, and you can map the data to get an array of arrays, which is [what DataTables expects](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).

```js
$(function() {
  const data = [{
      "Name": "Stefano",
      "Surname": "Rxxxx",
      "Age": "45"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Surname": "Dummy",
      "Age": "50"
    }
  ];

  // get the first object's keys and dump them into an array of objects
  const columns = Object.keys(data[0]).map(i => ({title: i}));

  // get the values from each data object and add it to a new array of arrays
  const formattedData = data.map(i => Object.values(i));

  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: formattedData,
    columns: columns
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table id='example' class='display'></table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Answer refactored.